# maven: java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to open file from resources with Intellij or using java command with jar

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, filenotfoundexception

I've imported the [github's](https://github.com/java8/Java8InAction) project from the book "Java 8 In Action" in intellij as a maven project.

The module structure is the following:

[image]

Then, i'm executing the Main method from the ExecuteAround class directly from Intellij (right click -> execute main...)

```
public static void main(String ...args) throws IOException{

    // method we want to refactor to make more flexible
    String result = processFileLimited();
    System.out.println(result);

    System.out.println("---");

    String oneLine = processFile((BufferedReader b) -> b.readLine());
    System.out.println(oneLine);

    String twoLines = processFile((BufferedReader b) -> b.readLine() + b.readLine());
    System.out.println(twoLines);

}

public static String processFileLimited() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                 new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lambdasinaction/chap3/data.txt"))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}


public static String processFile(BufferedReaderProcessor p) throws IOException {
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lambdasinaction/chap3/data.txt"))){
        return p.process(br);
    }

}

public interface BufferedReaderProcessor{
    public String process(BufferedReader b) throws IOException;

}
```

And then, i'm getting a FileNotFoundException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: lambdasinaction\chap3\data.txt
```

If a execute a "maven package", in the jar, the data.txt file is directly included in the chap3 folder/package but i get the same error if I execute:

```
java -classpath lambdasinaction-1.0.jar lambdasinaction.chap3.executeAround
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: lambdasinaction\chap3\data.txt (Le chemin d?accès spécifié est introuvable)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at lambdasinaction.chap3.ExecuteAround.processFileLimited(ExecuteAround.java:23)
        at lambdasinaction.chap3.ExecuteAround.main(ExecuteAround.java:9)
```

1- Why is it not running directly from intellij?  The file is correctly in the resource folder.

2 - This is probably most important: Why is it not running when executing the programm directly from the command line?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a Java program, relative filenames like `lambdasinaction/chap3/data.txt` are resolved against the current working directory:

- when you start your program with Intellij default settings, the current directory is the one containing the `.idea` folder (also contains `pom.xml`, `*.iml`, `*.ipr`, and so on)
- when using the command line the current directory can be printed out with `pwd` on Linux and `cd` on Windows

The files are put under `src/main/resources` and so unless the current directory is that `resources` you'll always get `FileNotFoundException`'s. Likely your program will not find your resources once deployed.

Good news is that directory is special for Maven and Maven-compatible tools (like Intellij) because the contents are available as classpath resources - it means you will always be able to read those files with

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/lambdasinaction/chap3/data.txt");
```

Note: I didn't use the filesystem (FileReader) to resolve the filename, but an (absolute) classpath resource identifier.

Comment: Does it mean that Filereader is only able to open file relative to the current path (or with full path as parameter) and so is not able to open files packaged in a jar?

Comment: Exactly. `FileReader` uses the filesystem. Pacakged resources must be located with the `ClassLoader` `via getClass().getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: Am facing a similar issue, I have a multi module maven project and getting same error. Also when checked am not finding the resource file generated in the target folder. Any help on this?

Answer (score 3):

Use **`"src/main/resources/lambdasinaction/chap3/data.txt"`** instead of `"lambdasinaction/chap3/data.txt"`

Comment: Using the complete path is working if I run the Main method from intellij directly but is still not working if i try executing it from the jar.

Comment: Could you add your /build folder? Does the .jar contain the data.txt?

Comment: In the target folder, the data.txt file is directly in the chap3 folder sitting next to the ExecuteAround.Class file (same in the jar file)  As additional info, i've left the project untouched.  This is the source code from the authors of the book.