# Difference from running application in IntellJ and running JAR file

Tags: java, file, jar, path

I came across a situation when i would run application in intellJ and everything runs smoothly , then i would create a jar using maven install command and try running it manually from command line, the results are the following :

Command Line

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: api\src\main\resources\FAQ.pdf (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at test.test.paisy.test.test.domain.email.FaqAttachment.pdfToBytes(FaqAttachment.java:27) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

Questions:

1. What is the difference between running Jar and running App in
   IntelliJ
2. Why would it complain about file path when it finds it
   successfully by running it in ItelliJ

Path to file

```
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("api/src/main/resources/FAQ.pdf"))) {
                this.bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use relative path, it needs to be started from the src folder, like this

```
new File("src/main/resources/FAQ.pdf")
```

But the best way is to use

```
InputStream inputStream = ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("FAQ.pdf");
```

So that the path won't be relative to that static path.

Don't forget to replace `ClassName` with the name of your current class

*Make sure to clean the build and then rebuild before running.*

For more detail take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601805/5988526)

Comment: this new FileInputStream(new File(ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource("FAQ.pdf").getFile())); - this wont work if you build jar

Comment: @BorisChistov can you explain why?

Comment: because file can only work with filesystem resources. And you have resource from classpath inside jar.

Comment: @BorisChistov , yes I was reading about that after you posted your comment, thanks for the information, I removed it from the answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, first in this code `new File("api/src/main/resources/FAQ.pdf")` you have relative path. So it depends on the property `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and form absolute path based on this property.

When you run jar file this property is set to your current directory
for example you have dir structure

```
root
  dir1
  dir2
    java-file.jar
```

`cd /root/dir1`

`java -jar ../dir2/jar-file.jar` - then your user.dir = /root/dir1 and your file will be searched in /root/dir1/api/src/main/resources/FAQ.pdf

In Idea you can specify working directory in run configuration.

Beter way to get data from resource directory, is to do something like this
`YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(("FAQ.pdf")`